# Namespaces “kube-system” is forbidden

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I’m having a problem when I install ebs-csi-driver for AWS EKS
I used the account with administratoraccess to install via was console but had an error “namespaces “kube-system” is forbidden: User “eks:addon-manager” cannot patch resource “namespaces” in API group “” in the namespace “kube-system””
I don’t know why the administrator permission can not install add-on.
I also tried to create IAM role but follow Link but receive error : Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts “ebs-csi-controller-sa” not found

I just started with Kubernetes so don’t know how t resolve,
Anyone can help ?

I follow [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-ebs-csi.html)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, after manually adding "patch" permission under namespace rule the installation was completed. I used the following command to edit that resource.

```
kubectl edit clusterrole eks:addon-manager
```

Hope this works for you :)

pd: I assume that this is needed only during the installation so after the I removed that permission.

Comment: Can you be more specific and possibly provide example?

Comment: This is part of the problem maybe, but there is another thing I have to fix before the whole problem solved. https://repost.aws/questions/QUEAwOTFmCTLG-SzJQOhkx3w/accessdenied-when-create-ebs-csi-driver

Answer (score 0):

While creating addon by default it inherit role of nodegroup, by giving permission of "AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" to your nodegroup's role might solve this issue.